Comedy movie about a murder in small town?
I can't remember the title of a comedy movie in which the protagonist (a middle aged woman) moves from a big city (if I remember correctly it was London) to a small town, in which a small cooking competition takes place. At some point a murder happens and she starts investigating. If I'm not wrong the title involves the name of this woman and the name of a cake or something baked followed by "of death" or something like that. It was very funny and it was released after 2010. Can you help me? I hope I was clear enough. Thank you:)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder,_She_Baked ?

Unfortunately it is not! It was just a single movie. I'm going to check out your suggestion for sure though :) thank you for your answer

Hi Jules. Do you remember anything else about the plot (however trivial)? Specific scenes? The actors or what they looked like? Where you saw it?

@Walt user23614 found the title, thank you so much for the comment though !

Agatha Raisin and the Quiche of Death by M. C. Beaton
Originally a two part TV movie but now a Sky TV series in 2016.

Thank you so much! I've been trying to remember the title for 2 weeks now :)
